# JdbcPagingItemReader with multiple select query

Tags: sql, oracle11g, spring-batch

I 'd like to write a JdbcPagingItemReader with a complex query like:

**select xxx from yyy where a=b and c = (select max(f) from yyy where a=b)**

...with parameters.

Here is how I wrote my query:

```
<bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="selectClause" value="SELECT ohrefnum" />
            <property name="fromClause" value="FROM orderhdr_all" />
            <property name="whereClause"
                value="WHERE customer_id =: CUSTOMER_ID AND ohentdate = (SELECT MAX (ohentdate) FROM orderhdr_all WHERE customer_id =: CUSTOMER_ID)" />
            <property name="sortKey" value="ohrefnum" />
        </bean>
```

but it raise the following error: `java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem origin. It was simply the space character after the "=:"

It should be

WHERE customer_id =:CUSTOMER_ID)

and not

WHERE customer_id **=:** CUSTOMER_ID)